# Doubt related to interface

Tags: solidity, erc-20, dapp-development

We know openzeppelin has an interface named `IERC20.sol`, my doubt is related to interface.
As this interface has functions like:

```
function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
```

My question is, is this interface usable because there are a contract named `ERC20` and this contract has implementations of these functions? like this:

```
function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _transfer(owner, to, amount);
        return true;
    }

function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }
```

If `ERC20` would not have implementation of these function wouldn't `IERC20` work? I saw `IERC20` did not imported `ERC20`, so how it will make the connection? If we don't do `IERC20(address_of_ERC20)` then the interface won't work anymore??

Answer (score 1):

`IERC20` is an interface for `ERC20`.

It defines required functions, **but it doesn't provide implementation**. It makes sure that the `ERC20` contract implements these functions.

You can use `IERC20` to interact with any contract that follows the `ERC20` standard.

Connection between `IERC20` and `ERC20` is not automatic.

You need to specify the address of the ERC20 contract when you use the IERC20 interface.

Example:

Deploy ERC20 contract, get its address: 0x1234...
Use `IERC20` interface in another contract, and provide `ERC20` contract's address:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract MyContract {
    IERC20 private _token;

    constructor(address tokenAddress) {
        _token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
    }

    function transferToken(address to, uint256 amount) public {
        _token.transfer(to, amount);
    }
}
```

Here, `MyContract` uses `IERC20` to interact with the deployed `ERC20` contract at the specified address. If `ERC20` didn't implement `IERC20` functions, it would simply fail.

Additionally, you can ensure your contract is **IERC20 compatible** by **inheriting** from the IERC20 interface as follow:

```
contract MyContract is IERC20
```

This ensures that your contract has implemented all the functions defined in the IERC20.